# Counting the number of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> **Problem** In each of the following $6$ digit numbers: $333333, 201102, 123123$; every digit appears at least twice. Find the number of such $6$-digit natural numbers.

---

I have done this problem using case work.

1. Those numbers containing exactly 3 distinct digits,
2. those numbers containing exactly 2 distinct digits, and similarly
3. those numbers containing only 1 digit

Also Case 1 and 2 involved two sub-cases each for numbers with/without 0.

But I want to know if there is a less bashy solution. 
Please help.

Comment: Someone please help me with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't go straight to the answer, but yes, I can reduce cases and simplify computations.

The idea is to always keep $A$ at start, and let $B$ and $C$ assume any value including $0$.
So the 1st multiplier will always be $9$, and we only need to choose $B,C$ and permute the 5 digits.

$A|AAAAA: 9$

$A|AAABB: 9\binom91\binom{5}{3,2}$

$A|AABBB: 9\binom91\binom{5}{2,3}$

$A|ABBBB: 9\binom91\binom{5}{1,4}$

$A|ABBCC: 9\binom92\binom{5}{1,2,2}$

Do check for typos in the formulations !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have these cases:
AAAAAA
AAAA00
AAA000
AA0000
AAAABB
AAABBB
AABBBB
AABB00
AABBCC
How many ways can you rearrange each of those, and give nonzero values to each of $A<B<C$?

Comment: Thanks.                 Yes, I did like this only to get $9+9 \times 10 +9\times 10+ 9 \times 5 + \dbinom{9}{2}\frac{6!}{4!2!}+ \dbinom{9}{2}\frac{6!}{3!3!}+ \dbinom{9}{2}\frac{6!}{4!2!}+\dbinom{9}{2}\dbinom{5}{2}\frac{6!}{8}+\dbinom{9}{3}\frac{6!}{8}=11754$

Comment: But @Michael, I am looking for a method (if its possible) that can do this problem without so many cases.

Comment: I can't think of a way to get straight to the answer.